# Angel One Communication with federation

Tags: star-trek

How is it that the inhabitants of angel one know of the federation when they have a policy on not making first contact until warp drive os established (TNG: first contact). Data says their level of technology is similar to mid 20 century on Earth, we were no way near establishing antimatter.

Comment: +1 for not posting this picture; http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/6/60/Angel_I_fashion.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/480?cb=20120808200702&path-prefix=en

Comment: @Richard hahahahahahaha +1